# Stuck on Bulk Compress using Python & Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

My goal is to implement an endpoint which performs a serverless bulk compress job and shares the download link of that zip in the end. Ofcourse, all the compressing will happen on the GCP. So far, this is what I've done, and I am getting a 401 unauthorized response.

My project is running in docker, and I am already passing the path of serviceaccount.json as environmental variable in the docker-compose file.

```
@strawberry.field
    async def download_photos_backup(self, order_id: str, info: RequestInfo) -> Optional[bool]:
        try:
            with context(info).session as session:
                # grabbing all photos associated with order
                photos = session.query(Photo).where(Photo.order_id == order_id).all()

                prefix = str(uuid4())

                # copying photos to export bucket
                for photo in photos:
                    
                    copy_blob(
                        bucket_name=Bucket.ORIGINAL_PHOTOS,
                        blob_name=photo.url, 
                        destination_bucket_name=Bucket.EXPORT,
                        destination_blob_name=f"photos_{prefix}/{photo.url}"
                        )
                    
                
                # Creating Compress Job on GCP Dataflow
                
                PROJECT_ID = "mystudiopro-nonprod"
                LOCATION   = "us-central1"
                VERSION    = "latest"

                JOB_NAME   = "compress1"

                BUCKET_NAME = "mystudiopro-dev-export"

                ZIP_BUCKET_NAME = "mystudiopro-dev-zip"

                req_url = f"https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{LOCATION}/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://dataflow-templates-{LOCATION}/{VERSION}/Bulk_Compress_GCS_Files"
                
                body = {
                    "jobName": JOB_NAME,
                    "parameters": {
                        "inputFilePattern": f"gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/photos_{prefix}/*.png",
                        "outputDirectory": f"gs://{ZIP_BUCKET_NAME}/compressed",
                        "outputFailureFile": f"gs://{ZIP_BUCKET_NAME}/failed/failure.csv",
                        "compression": "GZIP"
                    },
                    "environment": { "zone": "us-central1-f" },
                }

                res = requests.post(url = req_url, data=body)
                

                return True

        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
            return None
```

Using Python, I want to generate a bulk compress job, perform polling, and detect the completition of my job on my server, and grab the link of the zip in the end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where in your code are you getting the error? I noticed that your REST API call to Dataflow does not contain the required HTTP `Authorization` header.